# Ubuntu Linux freezes after boot up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, freeze, grub

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu Linux 11.04 under [Lenovo G570](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=lenovo%20g570&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=14046775610918256768&sa=X&ei=Zeu4T4eWOojKhAfkv-TUCA&ved=0CHEQ8wIwBA), when I choose Ubuntu Linux 11.04 in grub menu, Ubuntu freezes in a black screen and even hiting ctrl+alt+f1-f10 didn't make any difference. Is there any suggestion that I can find out what's the problem ?

Comment: Do a fresh installation of the current version Ubuntu 12.04 instead; it might be a hardware issue that has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a LiveCD, mount the hard drive so you can access it, then navigate to the logs.